# MongoDB geometry query not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have stored some GeoJSON points in my db and I cannot query them using the new geoWithin (2.4.1).

Here is the indexes for my collection:

```
> db.features1.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "sagedb.features1",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "geometry" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "sagedb.features1",
        "name" : "geometry_2dsphere"
    }
]
```

Here is the one document I have in my db

```
> db.features1.find();
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51672e677a62bb0000000003"), 
  "geometry" : { 
    "type" : "Point", 
    "coordinates" : [ -106.8610919, 49.665165099999996 ] }, 
  "__v" : 0 }
```

I am trying to run this query:

```
> db.features1.find( {
  geometry: { 
    $geoWithin: { 
      $geometry: { 
        type: "Polygon", 
        coordinates: [ [ [-180,-90], [-180,90], [180,90], [180,-90], [-180,-90] ] ] } } } });
```

But I get nothing back.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounding polygon must be < a hemisphere.  If it's greater than a hemisphere, it won't return anything.

This is missing from the 2.4.1 documentation.